# Textarea is required only when certain answers are chosen from two radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons (both required). So I need to make it so, that when the first radio button is set to Yes, you have to tell why in the textarea and when the second one is No you have to fill out why as well.

```
<h4>Are any of the item(s) missing?</h4>
Yes<input type ="radio" name ="missing" id = "missing1" value = "Yes" required>
No<input type ="radio" name ="missing" id = "missing2" value = "No" >
<div class = "lossnum">
    <h5>How many?</h5>
    <input type="number" name="lossnum" id = "lossnum" placeholder="0">
</div>
<h4>Question 2</h4>

Yes<input type ="radio" name ="putback" id = "putback1" value = "Yes" required>
No<input type ="radio" name ="putback" id = "putback2" value = "No">
```

Some things I have tried:

Just using a modal that shows up when buttons are chosen (modals never worked, so I gave up).

I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".lossnum").hide();
    $(".comments").hide();
    $(".returncomments").hide();

    $("#missing1").click(function () {
        $(".lossnum").show();
        $(".comments").show();
        $(".returncomments").show();
    });
    $("#missing2").click(function () {
        $(".lossnum").hide();
        $(".comments").hide();
        $(".returncomments").hide();
    });
     $("#putback2").click(function () {
        $(".comments").show();
        $(".returncomments").show();
    });
    $("#putback1").click(function () {
        $(".comments").hide();
        $(".returncomments").hide();
    });
});
```

This works for what it's meant to do. But just wasn't what I wanted with things closing when they shouldn't, and the textarea could still just be ignored.

Comment: Please, show attempted solution

Comment: well completely unrelated but, why is cursing censored on here? i mean cursing is probably the one language i know best

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362)

Answer (score 0):

first hide: `.lossnum {display:none;}`

then show it if press yes:

```
 $('input[value="Yes]').click(function() {
       $(this).next('.lossnum').show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

For easier understanding maybe:

```
$('input[name=missing]').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).val() === "Yes");
    if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
        $('#lossnum').show();
    } else {
        $('#lossnum').hide();

    };
})
```

-> [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqe5c33o/4/)

Don't know if I got you rigth ...

I made a second Fiddle for showing a comment area when first radiogroup is yes and second is no.

```
$('input[name=missing]').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
        $('#lossnum').show();
    } else {
        $('#lossnum').hide();

    };
})

$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
    if ($('input[name=missing]:checked').val() === 'Yes' && $('input[name=putback]:checked').val() === 'No') {
        $('#comment').show();
    } else {
        $('#comment').hide();
    }
})
```

->[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqe5c33o/5/)